customizing order of x-axis labels with unfixed labels in ggplot2
I want to customize x-axis label in ggplot2.
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(SUBJID = 1001:1010,
                Level = sample(c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"), 10, replace = T),
                Value = runif(10, min = 200, max = 500))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Level, Value)) +
  geom_boxplot()


For known X label, usually I use this code to change order.
df$Level = factor(df$Level, levels = c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"))
  
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Level, Value)) +
  geom_boxplot()


But I added the subject number in X label, so the label is not a known character.
df %>%
  group_by(Level) %>%
  mutate(
    SUBJN = n_distinct(SUBJID),
    Level_N = paste(Level, "(N=", SUBJN, ")")
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Level_N, Value)) +
  geom_boxplot()


The X label is not a fixed character, so I cannot use the code I previously used.
How to customize order of X label in this situation?
I tried fct_reorder, and the plot was not what I wanted.
df %>%
  group_by(Level) %>%
  mutate(
    SUBJN = n_distinct(SUBJID),
    Level_N = paste(Level, "(N=", SUBJN, ")") |> factor() |> fct_reorder(as.numeric(Level))
  ) %>%
  boxplot(Value ~ Level_N)



Take a look at https://forcats.tidyverse.org/. fct_reorder or fct_inorder might be appropriate. Do you have a sense what general rule(s) should be used to specify the order?

@JonSpring . Nope, I have no idea. I looked at the link you left, and still don't know how to reorder unfixed characters with this package. Thank you.

mutate(Level_N = factor(Level_N) |> forcats::fct_reorder(Level))… then the new names will have the order of Level

@JonSpring, it still doesn't work. It reported an error with the codes you provided directly, so I modified it based on the link you left. You can see it in the updated question.

It's always best to share what error codes you see. I'm presuming the issue was that fct_reorder doesn't know what to do if the referenced ordering variable is a factor, but it worked for me if I modified to Level_N = paste(Level, "(N=", SUBJN, ")") |> factor() |> forcats::fct_reorder(as.numeric(Level))

@JonSpring, the plot is still like what I post in question. It's not what I want.

It looks ordered correctly when I set the Level order, then group_by(Level) and do the modified Level_N I suggested. The leftmost plot category is "Normal (N=3 )" [should have used paste0].

You can create a mapping of the original levels to the new ones and then use left_join to sort them according to the desired order (I could not reproduce the same plot, even with the same seed, but anyway, the order of the axis labels is that matters).
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Level) %>%
  mutate(
    SUBJN = n_distinct(SUBJID),
    Level_N = paste(Level, "(N=", SUBJN, ")")
  )

mapping <- distinct(df2, Level, Level_N)

levels_N <- data.frame(Level = c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe")) %>%
    left_join(mapping, by = "Level") %>%
    pull(Level_N)

df2$Level_N <- factor(df2$Level_N, levels = levels_N)

ggplot(df2, aes(Level_N, Value)) +
    geom_boxplot()


